# React-native app is never relaunched to handle location updates in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm trying to handle location updates in a react-native app while the app is terminated. After several days of failing to get [react-native-background-geolocation](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation) or CLLocationManager working consistently, I'm now trying to use the [intuit/LocationManager](https://github.com/intuit/LocationManager) pod, but my app is not re-launching in response to location updates (or maybe it's just not logging them?)

This is Intuit's example for handling a location based launch:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // If you start monitoring significant location changes and your app is subsequently terminated, the system automatically relaunches the app into the background if a new event arrives.
    // Upon relaunch, you must still subscribe to significant location changes to continue receiving location events. 
    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey]) {
        INTULocationManager *locMgr = [INTULocationManager sharedInstance];
        [locMgr subscribeToSignificantLocationChangesWithBlock:^(CLLocation *currentLocation, INTULocationAccuracy achievedAccuracy, INTULocationStatus status) {
            // This block will be executed with the details of the significant location change that triggered the background app launch,
            // and will continue to execute for any future significant location change events as well (unless canceled).
        }];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

And here is my code:

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  NSLog(@"--- Initializing application");

  INTULocationManager *locMgr = [INTULocationManager sharedInstance];
  [locMgr subscribeToSignificantLocationChangesWithBlock:^(CLLocation *currentLocation, INTULocationAccuracy achievedAccuracy, INTULocationStatus status) {
    // This block will be executed with the details of the significant location change that triggered the background app launch,
    // and will continue to execute for any future significant location change events as well (unless canceled).
    NSLog(@"--- location update");
  }];

  _app = application;

  id<RCTBridgeDelegate> moduleInitialiser = self;
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:moduleInitialiser launchOptions:launchOptions];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc]
    initWithBridge:bridge
    moduleName:@"GoNote"
    initialProperties:nil
  ];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  [FIRApp configure];
  [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];

  return YES;
}
```

To test this, I open the app in a simulator, wait for a location update (the app logs "location update"), then close the app (double press command-shift-h and swipe away the app). Then I wait with the simulator's debug location set to "Freeway drive".

From what I understand, the app should be launched in the background, and I should see the logs "Initializing application" and "location update", but this never happens.

I have these entries in my `info.plist` file:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>CHANGEME: NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>CHANGEME: NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>CHANGEME: NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</string>
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string>CHANGEME: NSMotionUsageDescription</string>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
```

Why isn't my app handling location updates?

Comment: Were you able to get this working? I am spending my time in the exact same scenario.

Answer (score 0):

iOS has several options how to correctly run the application in the background. These methods are enabled with iOS. We’ll use the one that your application will use and which we need. All services we can see in UIBackgroundModes array:

follow this link:-
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620568-allowsbackgroundlocationupdates?language=objc

If the application is in the foreground, we could simply stop monitoring and again start it after interval, for example using NSTimer. In this case, we have to think about the life of the application. The application runs in the background and during idle stops working.

**in iOS natively we can’t change the interval at which the system updates the user location. IOS updates position regularly every second, if have GPS signal.**

Application make background location update every 5 minutes do the following:

Go your Project "Target" -> Capabilities -> Background Modes -> select Location updates

My final procedure is **use NSTimer in the background** by using  **UIApplication:beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:.** This timer triggers periodically while the application runs in the background.

Now make location working when your app is in the background and send coordinates to web service or do anything with them every 5 minutes implement it like in the code below.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
//update location
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
 {
     NSLog(@"Location: %f, %f", newLocation.coordinates.longtitude, newLocation.coordinates.latitude);
 }

//run background task
-(voud)runBackgroundTask: (int) time
{
     //check if application is in background mode
     if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) 
     {
          //create UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier and create tackground task, which starts after time
            __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
           [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
              bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }]; 

          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue (DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

           NSTimer* t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time target:self selector:@selector(startTrackingBg) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
          [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:t forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
          [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

          });
       }
 }

 //starts when application switchs into backghround
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //check if application status is in background
    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) 
    {
        NSLog(@"start backgroun tracking from appdelegate");

        //start updating location with location manager
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    } 

     //change locationManager status after time
     [self runBackgroundTask:20];
}

 //starts with background task
 -(void)startTrackingBg{
     //write background time remaining
     NSLog(@"backgroundTimeRemaining: %.0f", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);
     //set default time
     int time = 60;
     //if locationManager is ON
     if (locationStarted == TRUE ) {
         //stop update location
         [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
         locationStarted = FALSE;
     }else{
          //start updating location
          [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
          locationStarted = TRUE;
          //ime how long the application will update your location
          time = 5;
    }
   [self runBackgroundTask:time];
 }

//application switchs back from background
 - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
 {
      locationStarted = FALSE;
      //stop updating
      [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
 }
```

Comment: Why is this so complicated? Why do you have to check if the app is in the background in the didEnterBackground lifecycle method? Will `applicationDidEnterBackground` ever be called when the app is in the foreground? Why do you call `startUpdatingLocation` in `applicationDidEnterBackground ` then call it again in `startTrackingBg` 20 seconds later? Why do you stop location updates in `startTrackingBg`? When you refer to the "background", does that include when the app is terminated?